# $\lim _{A \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-A}^{A} \frac{\sin(\lambda t)}{t}e^{itx}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Question: Find$$\lim _{A \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-A}^{A} \frac{\sin(\lambda t)}{t}e^{itx}dt$$for $\lambda >0$.

My attempt:
Let $f_{\lambda}=\chi_{[-\lambda,\lambda]}$. Then
$$\hat {f_{\lambda}}(t)=\sqrt{\frac {2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin \lambda t}{t}$$
where the hat denotes fourier transform.
Since $f_\lambda $,$\hat {f_\lambda} \in L^2$, by the Plancherel Theorem,
$$||\int_{-A}^{A}\frac{\sin\lambda t}{t}e^{itx}dt-\frac{1}{\pi}f_\lambda (x)||_2\rightarrow 0$$ as $A \rightarrow \infty$.

Hence we may choose a subsequence $(A_n)_{n\in  \mathbb N}$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $\int_{-A}^{A}\frac{\sin\lambda t}{t}e^{itx}dt$ converges to $\frac {1}{\pi}f(x)$ a.e. along $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Therefore, $\int_{-A}^{A}\frac{\sin\lambda t}{t}e^{itx}dt$ converges a.e. to $1/\pi$ if $x \in [-\lambda,\lambda]$ and a.e. to $0$ if $x \notin [-\lambda, \lambda]$.

Is this solution legitimate? Or had I made any mistake? Thanks and regards.